# Creating a simple model of search engine

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, constructor

This is a homework problem and I'm stuck for a long time.We are learning a bit about search engine technology that indexes the document counting the number of times each word appears in them.We have to create two classes; **Term** and **Document**

The **Term** class has: a String named word,int freq(counts frequencies of words),a constructor that takes in a word and a freq and initializes the object,get methods and set methods(but no set method for freq).

In the **Document** class,the question asks to create an array called *terms* that stores words of a string(given I split them by white spaces),double magnitude filed to measure sqrt(summation of(*terms*[i].freq)^2);where freq is the frequency of each distinct words in the string.I have to create a constructor that takes a single String argument as full text,converts that into lower case, splits that by white spaces.Next I have to create a static *sort* method without the help of java.util.Arrays to sort the string array alphabetically.Then I will create a *countDistinctStrings* method that takes in **sorted strings** as parameter,and counts unique number of words(ignoring the duplication).Then a method called *indexContent* that takes an array of words from a document as it's parameter,populates *terms* array, and calculates the **magnitude**, which I mentioned before.First the method determines how many distinct terms are in the original array, then creates a *terms* array of proper size.It puts unique strings into *terms* in sorted order and gives the frequencies in a table. The Output should look like this:
    + Enter the text of a document:
        **I wish I found some better sounds no one's ever heard I wish I had a   better voice that sang some better words**

> Term frequency list:
>   a~1,had~1,one's~1,that~1,better~3,heard~1,sang~1,voice~1,ever~1,I~4,some~2,wish~2,found~1,no~1,sounds~1,words~1.(but in a table) **Magnitude** 6.708

This is my attempt so far:**Term** class

```
class Term {
private String word;
private int freq;
Term(String word,int freq){
    this.word = word;
    this.freq = freq;
}

public String getWord()
{
    return word;
}

public int getFreq()
{
    return freq;
}

public void setFreq(int freq)
{
    this.freq = freq;
}

}
```

Then the **Document** class:(note the code is incomplete as I don't know how to take next step, i.e. how to get the sort array method into the other countDistinctStrings.I cannot even use my object to call methods,which will throw **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Document 
{
String text;
private double magnitude;
static String terms [];

Document(String text) {
this.text = text;
text = text.toLowerCase();
String [] terms = text.split("\\s+");
for ( String s : terms)
System.out.println(s);

}
private static void sort (String [] terms) {
    String tempVar;
    for (int i = 0; i < terms.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <terms.length ; j++) {
                 if(terms[i].compareTo(terms[j]) > 0) {
                        tempVar = terms [j];
                        terms [j ]= terms [i];
                        terms [i] = tempVar;
                 }
             }
         }
         }
private  void countDistinctStrings () {
   Document.sort(terms);
}


public double getMagnitude(){
return magnitude;
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the document text : ");
String text = input.nextLine();
Document object = new Document(text);
object.sort(terms);

}
}
```

I am a beginner.I would really appreciate someone's help and time in my learning process.This homework is now past due date but I really want to do it and understand it.

Comment: Afif, the first problem with your code is in the constructor of Document.  You incorrectly redefine terms.  Remove the 'String []' part so it is just 'terms = text.split... and you will get past the mistake.

Comment: @ Ian.Many thanks for the suggestion and now it doesn't throw nullpointer exception.However, I'm still not getting alphabetically sorted strings.

Comment: I ran your code, and it did sort in reverse order properly. If you want to sort in order, change the compareTo line from a '>' to '<'.

Comment: @Ian, it's not giving me order even after changing.Perhaps I'm calling it wrong way.Can you take a look at the main method?

Comment: We will run out of room in comments.  Have transferred to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the 'String []' from the constructor
2. Change the '>' to '<' on the compareTo line

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the document text : ");
       String text = input.nextLine();
       Document object = new Document(text);
       object.sort(terms);
       System.out.println("--- AFTER SORT ----");
       for (String s : terms)
           System.out.println(s);

   }
   ```

Output:

```
Enter the document text : 
I wish I found some better sounds no one's ever heard I wish I had a better voice that sang some better words
i
wish
i
found
some
better
sounds
no
one's
ever
heard
i
wish
i
had
a
better
voice
that
sang
some
better
words
--- AFTER SORT ----
a
better
better
better
ever
found
had
heard
i
i
i
i
no
one's
sang
some
some
sounds
that
voice
wish
wish
words
```

Comment: @ Ian,Yes it worked.Let's see if I can store them in an array and count the frequency in order to have the exact same output as mentioned in the question.But You helped me with the most difficult part.I was unable to find what was wrong but just a sign, "<", phew...god bless you.

Comment: Very well done Afif.  Mostly perfect code.  If you run into a problem with the next section, let me know.  Cheers.